# SSRS Expression Evaluation Issue Nested IIF/Switch

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, switch-statement, iif, ssrs-expression

Long-time reader, first time poster.

I've got a tricky situation with an SSRS Expression that I want to get help with.

I have, amongst others, 2 columns inside a Table named:

ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod
ActualMovementCurrentPeriod

I have 5 criteria that need to be applied in an expression to a third column.

They are as follows:

> If ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod = 0 AND
>   'ActualMovementCurrentPeriod-ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod'>0, return
>   "-100%"
>
> If ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod = 0 AND
>   'ActualMovementCurrentPeriod-ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod'<0, return
>   "+100%"
>
> If ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod <> 0 And If
>   'ActualMovementCurrentPeriod-ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod' is not an
>   error, and
>   ABS((ActualMovementCurrentPeriod-ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod) /
>   ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod) > 100%, return "Large"
>
> If ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod <> 0 And If
>   'ActualMovementCurrentPeriod-ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod' is not an
>   error, and
>   ABS((ActualMovementCurrentPeriod-ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod) /
>   ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod) < 20%, return "Minor"
>
> If ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod <> 0 And If
>   'ActualMovementCurrentPeriod-ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod' is not an
>   error and
>   ABS((ActualMovementCurrentPeriod-ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod)/ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod)
>   < 100% and > 20%, return
>   (ActualMovementCurrentPeriod-ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod)/ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod)

Those are the criteria the expression needs to return. I've tried a combination of SWITCH statements and IIF statements, but I can't get it to work.

Below is my code:

```
=SWITCH
    (
        SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) = 0.00 AND SUM(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) - SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) > 0.00, "-100%",
        SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) = 0.00 AND SUM(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) - SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) < 0.00, "+100%",
        SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) <> 0 AND (SUM(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) - SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) <> 0.99123131414) AND (ABS(SUM(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) - ABS(SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value))) / ABS(SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) > 1.00, "Large",
        SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) <> 0 AND (SUM(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) - SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) <> 0.9912313141) AND (ABS(SUM(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) - ABS(SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value))) / ABS(SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) < 0.20, "Minor",  
        SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) <> 0 AND (SUM(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) - SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) <> 0.9912313141) AND ((ABS(SUM(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) - ABS(SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value))) / ABS(SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) > 0.20 AND (ABS(SUM(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) - ABS(SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value))) / ABS(SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value))) < 1.00, (SUM(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) - SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) / SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)
    )
```

This returns correctly for "Large", "Minor" and the final criterion which will be a % value of 2 columns. The problem I'm having is that it's returning an error when the first 2 criteria are met, e.g, ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod = 0 AND ActualMovementCurrentPeriod-ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod results in say "5" - it should return "-100%" but instead returns an #Error.

The interesting thing is that if I remove the last 3 lines in my SWITCH statement, so I only have, say:

```
=SWITCH
(
    SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) = 0.00 AND SUM(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) - SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) > 0.00, "-100%",
    SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) = 0.00 AND SUM(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) - SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) < 0.00, "+100%"
    )
```

It returns the correct values for the same rows which return an #Error when the other 3 lines are in there! I can't for the life of me figure this out. I've tried nested IIF statements to no avail.

Can anyone please tell me what I could be doing wrong? As far as I knew, a SWITCH statement will return the first value which is TRUE based on the order in which the statements are there. Why won't it return "-100%" or "+100%" when the criteria is met and the last 3 lines of my SWITCH statement are also there?

Any help would be awesome!

EDIT:

I've figured out the issue.

I managed to figure it out in the end. Even though the SWITCH statement would return a true value for the first expression, it looks like the SWITCH statement won't actually return that value until after it's evaluated EVERY expression in the statement. When it was trying to evaluate the last 3 statements, there was a divide by zero occurring and that's why it would return #ERROR even though the first expression evaluated to true.

Strange behaviour because I would've thought that once the SWITCH statement found a true value, it wouldn't bother to evaluate the other ones.

My solution was to wrap IIF statements around the final 3 expressions to avoid divide by zero.

Code is below:

```
=SWITCH
    (
        SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) = 0.00 AND SUM(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) - SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) > 0.00, "-100%",
        SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) = 0.00 AND SUM(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) - SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) < 0.00, "+100%",
        SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) <> 0 AND (SUM(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) - SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) <> 0.99123131414) AND IIf(ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) = 0, 0, ABS(Sum(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) - ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value))) / IIf(ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) = 0, 1, ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value))) > 1.00, "Large",
        SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) <> 0 AND (SUM(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) - SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) <> 0.9912313141) AND IIf(ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) = 0, 0, ABS(Sum(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) - ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value))) / IIf(ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) = 0, 1, ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value))) < 0.20, "Minor",    
        SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) <> 0 AND (SUM(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) - SUM(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value) <> 0.9912313141) AND (IIf(ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) = 0, 0, ABS(Sum(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) - ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value))) / IIf(ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) = 0, 1, ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value))) > 0.20 AND IIf(ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) = 0, 0, ABS(Sum(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) - ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value))) / IIf(ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) = 0, 1, ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)))) < 1.00, IIf(ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) = 0, 0, ABS(Sum(Fields!ActualMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) - ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value))) / IIf(ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value)) = 0, 1, ABS(Sum(Fields!ForecastMovementCurrentPeriod.Value))),
    TRUE, "Error"
    )
```

I still find it strange that SWITCH won't terminate evaluation of the entire block once it finds the first true value - seems like a waste of computation to me.

Anyway thanks guys!

Comment: Sounds like a data types problem.  What does the error you get say?

Comment: Try to cast all Fields in Expression and make sure case divide by 0 are not happen.

Comment: Thanks guys - I managed to figure it out in the end. Even though the SWITCH statement would return a true value for the first expression, it looks like the SWITCH statement won't actually return that value until after it's evaluated EVERY expression in the statement.

When it was trying to evaluate the last 3 statements, there was a divide by zero occurring and that's why it would return #ERROR even though the first expression evaluated to true.

Strange behaviour because I would've thought that once the SWITCH statement found a true value, it wouldn't bother to evaluate the other ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think your last switch statement has a parenthesis in the wrong place.  This is what I see if I break it down:

```
    SUM(cpv) <> 0 
    AND (SUM(mcp) - SUM(cpv) <> 0.9912313141)
    AND 
    (
        (ABS(SUM(mcp)) - ABS(SUM(cpv))) / ABS(SUM(cpv)) > 0.20 
        AND (ABS(SUM(mcp)) - ABS(SUM(cpv))) / ABS(SUM(cpv))  -- This is not valid calculation
    ) < 1.00,
      (SUM(mcp) - SUM(cpv)) / SUM(cpv)
```

That sixth line is not a valid calculation, because you closed the parens too early.  you need to put the last parens *after* the "< 1.00".  Like this:

```
    SUM(cpv) <> 0 
    AND (SUM(mcp) - SUM(cpv) <> 0.9912313141)
    AND 
    (
        (ABS(SUM(mcp)) - ABS(SUM(cpv))) / ABS(SUM(cpv)) > 0.20 
        AND (ABS(SUM(mcp)) - ABS(SUM(cpv))) / ABS(SUM(cpv)) < 1.00
    ), -- close the parens after 
      (SUM(mcp) - SUM(cpv)) / SUM(cpv)
```

To further simplify, i would try using a BETWEEN statement instead, as it eliminates duplication:

```
    SUM(cpv) <> 0 
    AND (SUM(mcp) - SUM(cpv) <> 0.9912313141)
    AND 
    (
        ((ABS(SUM(mcp)) - ABS(SUM(cpv))) / ABS(SUM(cpv))) between 0.20 and 1.00 
    ),
      (SUM(mcp) - SUM(cpv)) / SUM(cpv)
```